# Hibernate, @ManyToOne / @OneToMany, children added not fetched with parent

Tags: java, hibernate

I have more or less something like this setup with hibernate and h2/postgres (both are not working properly)

```
@Entity
class A {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "a", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    List<B> bs;

}

@Entity
class B {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    long id;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER) 
    A a;
}
```

Now, there is @Transactional repository with save/update/getAll/getById methods.

My problem is when I do following:

```
A a = new A();
save(a);

B b = new B();
b.a = a;
save(b);

A anotherA = getById(a.id);
```

object called "anotherA" does not have any B objects in "bs" field.

Should I do something to make it happen or there is something wrong with my approach?

In addition, when I call last line after some time the bs are filled, so I suspect that it might be problem with session and A object that is stored there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must make sure you'd applying the relation on both sides of the relation like as follows:

```
A a = new A();
session.save( a );

B b = new B();
b.setA( a );
a.getBList().add( b );
session.save( b );
```

Typically to avoid having to put this type of code in various places of my application, I typically expose an actor method that manages this relationship for me.

```
// a method inside B
public void applyA(A a) {
  // if B is currently related to A, break the relation
  if ( this.a != null ) {
    this.a.getBList().remove( this );
  }
  // apply the relation to both sides
  this.a = a;
  if ( a != null ) {
    a.getBList().add( this );
  }
}
```

Similarly you could add a similar method to A

```
public void applyB(B b) {
  if ( b != null && !this.bList.contains( b ) ) {
    b.apply( this );
  }
}
```